# Another C0006 Metadata file could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, file-not-found

We have a near-dirt-simple console app that connects to a database we're using in an MVC app.  When I went to compile the console app, I got the C0006 error on the EntityFramework.dll and EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll files.  Other console apps that we have compiled fine.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the repo had spaces in it.  When we cloned the repo, those spaces were converted to %20.  Removing those %20s fixed it.  I assume that some portions of the code were taking the %20 literally, and others were converting them to spaces.